# geom_text changes length of the bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot defined this way:

```
ggplot(pol, aes(x=angle, y=distance )) + coord_polar(start=0) + geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 360), expand=c(0,0), lim=c(0, 360))+
  scale_area()
```

Here presents no problem, but when I add text at the end of each geom_bar (shown is the value of the length of the bar) in this way:

```
geom_text(aes(y = 30,label = text),size=2)
```

It seems that the parameter y changes the length of the bars, so I do not understand why. I just want to set the y position of the text.

Comment: Example data would be nice.

Comment: Maybe `y = 30` should be outside of `aes()` not inside? If you are _setting_ to a single value, that doesn't go in `aes()` which is for _mapping_ variables to aesthetics.

Comment: @joran yes you're right! How can I set the "y" with the maximum value of the bar?

Comment: `aes(y = distance,...)` maybe? If it's the same, you probably don't even need to re-map it; it should cascade down from the `ggplot()` call.